# WPF: Fake unselection in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selectionchanged

I try binding a `List` to `ComboBox` and select the first item.

I set `myCombobox.SelectedIndex = 0;` and it works. `SelectionChanged` is fired and I make some changes to other controls inside the handler.
But right after that `SelectionChanged` is fired again and it looks as if my selected item is reset, so it is null again, `SelectedIndex` is `-1`.

Does any body know why this weird "reset" is happening?
I have tried subscribing after I selected an item, but this "reset" occurs anyway

in XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="myCombobox" DisplayMemberPath="Description"
     SelectedValue="{Binding Id}" SelectedValuePath="Id" 
     Text="{Binding Description}"/>
```

in cs:

```
myCombobox.ItemsSource = itemList; //List<T>, T has Id and Description
myCombobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
myCombobox.SelectionChanged += SelectionChangedMethod;
```

Comment: Please add `SelectionChangedMethod` body.

Comment: I did setting of `ItemsSource` before the window is rendered. I have done it after that, and now this reset doesn't occur after I select an item.